# how to find out the period of a signal based on its autocorrelation

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I'm wondering how the autocorrelation result of a periodic sinal, which period is unkown,  reveals information about this perdio, I know how to calcule the autocorrelation, but I just don't understand  how can read the period ! from the result!  can anyone explain how to do it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically the first peak in the autocorrelation corresponds to the period of the waveform. So for example a 50 Hz sine wave will have a peak in its autocorrelation at t = 1/50 = 0.02s.